# Consulta SQL para ordenar registros con un orden alfabético diferente

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, ordenamiento

Requiero ordenar una consulta con otro orden alfabético, con la diferencia de que haya letras compuestas de al menos dos caracteres por ejemplo en castellano tenemos 'ch', 'll', 'rr'. Por ejemplo letras compuestas ch y (digamos) cr:

Orden alfabético normal: a b c d e f g h i j ...

Orden alfabético deseado: a b c ch cr d e f g h i j ...

```
Orden común   Orden deseado
Aca           Aca          
Ace           Ace
Acha          Aci
Ache          Aco
Aci           Acu
Aco           Acha
Acra          Ache
Acri          Acra
Acu           Acri
Ada           Ada
... etc.      ... etc.
```

Pista: se me recomendó que las Expresiones Regulares (REGEXP en SQL) hacen cosas así, pero no encontré su uso en ordenamiento.

Gracias anteladas

**PD.** Quisiera dejar claro que mi pregunta es sobre SQL y no sobre el castellano implantado en SQL, es para su aplicación en otros lenguajes.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En este sitio se pide que muestres que intentaste hasta ahora. Entiendo que esta consulta es un tanto mas compleja como para haber intentado algo, pero es para evitar que recibas respuestas con cosas que ya probaste y no funcionaron.

Comment: Si se trata de un orden más complejo, como parece ser el caso, es necesario que indiques claramente **cuál sería el criterio a seguir** para establecer el orden. Por ejemplo: *que ordene primero por vocales, y luego que trate las combinaciones de "las consonantes tal, tal y tal" como una sola letra*. Entonces expertos en REGEX como @Mariano podrán darte una solución óptima. Tu pregunta no era del todo clara al principio, por eso pensé que se podría resolver con `COLLATE`. De todos modos, según tu nueva edición, mi respuesta sigue siendo válida para lo que quieres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El orden que buscas es el de la collation `utf8_spanish2_ci` de Mysql, el cual trata precisamente a `Ch` como una letra que va colocada después de la letra `C` ([ver aquí](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_spanish2_ci.html)).

Entonces puedes resolverlo de dos maneras:

## 1.

Indicando que quieres aplicar esa `COLLATION` a la columna al seleccionarla y ordenando por ella.

Consideremos la tabla siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prueba_collation 
(
    colNormal VARCHAR(15),
    colCollate VARCHAR(15) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Tiene dos columnas, una llamada `colNormal` sin ningún `COLLATE` establecido, y otra llamada `colCollate` con `COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci`.

Si quieres ordenar la columna que no tiene `COLLATE`, puedes indicar en el `SELECT` que **para este caso** quieres que a esa columna se aplique `COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci`:

```
-- Orden deseado estableciendo COLLATION en el SELECT
SELECT 
colNormal COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci colNormalTest
FROM prueba_collation ORDER BY colNormalTest;
```

**Resultado:**

```
colNormal
Aca
Ace
Aci
Aco
Acha
Ache
Achi
```

Sin ese COLLATE los datos quedarían así:

```
-- Orden no deseado (sin el COLLATION adecuado)
SELECT 
colNormal 
FROM prueba_collation ORDER BY colNormal;
```

**Resultado:**

```
colNormal
Aca
Ace
Acha
Ache
Achi
Aci
Aco
```

## 2.

Poniendo el collate `utf8_spanish2_ci` directamente a la columna en el `CREATE TABLE` o en un `ALTER TABLE` (sería la forma en que hemos creado la columna `colCollate` en el código, más arriba).

Esta opción sólo sería viable si **siempre** necesitarás los datos ordenados de esa forma, porque de lo contrario, no sería muy buena idea hacer depender a una columna de un COLLATE que sólo usarás en ciertos casos.

Si te decides por usar la columna declarada con ese `COLLATE` en ese caso la consulta se haría con normalidad, sin tener que volver a especificar el collate:

```
-- Orden deseado definiendo COLLATION en el CREATE TABLE 
SELECT 
colCollate 
FROM prueba_collation ORDER BY colCollate;
```

**Resultado:**

```
colCollate
Aca
Ace
Aci
Aco
Acha
Ache
Achi
```

---

## Prueba de concepto

En el enlace siguiente puedes ver una prueba de concepto del código usado en esta respuesta.
Espero te sirva.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/HAB40515)**</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias A. Cedano, sin embargo aclaré que no me refiero a la implantación del castellano en SQL, sino a generar formas de ordenar con caracteres dobles de otros posibles lenguajes. Editaré la pregunta.

Comment: @Pillqu Cedano es mucho mas experto que yo con esta base, pero es muy probable que tengas otros servicios de ordenamiento tambien para otros lenguajes.

Comment: @Pillqu en tu pregunta haces referencia a las expresiones regulares... sin embargo considero que, en vez de REGEX, podrías aplicar un `COLLATE` adecuado según el caso. En la respuesta hay un ejemplo basado en los datos que tú indicas, si necesitas otro tipo de orden, entonces sería cuestión de [usar el `COLLATE` adecuado para ese caso](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html). Sería lo mismo que un REGEX, pero más eficiente, más claro y menos propenso a errores, en mi opinión. En el enlace podrás ver la infinidad de `COLLATE` con que cuenta MySQL...

Comment: @A.Cedano, fue justo lo que necesito, no hay el collate preciso para mí pero al parecer es posible crear uno propio. Gracias

Comment: @Pillqu me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.