# Cómo hacer subconsulta insensible a mayus/minus

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
"UPDATE articulos_nuevos a INNER JOIN diccionario d ON d.proveedor = a.proveedor AND d.categoria = a.categoria 
    SET a.Familia_ERP = d.Familia_ERP, a.Subfamilia_erp = d.Subfamilia_erp"
```

Actualmente, tengo un proveedor en diccionario en mayúsculas y otro proveedor en articulos_nuevos en minúsculas, que son el mismo pero la consulta no lo reconoce. Lo ideal sería que toda la consulta fuera insensible a mayus/minus. Sé que se puede hacer con UPPER, pero no me parece práctico hacer algo así:

```
"UPDATE articulos_nuevos a INNER JOIN diccionario d ON UPPER(d.proveedor = a.proveedor) AND UPPER(d.categoria = a.categoria) 
    SET a.Familia_ERP = d.Familia_ERP, a.Subfamilia_erp = d.Subfamilia_erp"
```

Digo que no me parece práctico porque en otras consultas que haya más condiciones tienes que repetir UPPER un montón de veces. ¿De qué forma puede hacerse que sea lo más limpia posible? Gracias, saludos.

P.D. Estoy manejando esto con PHP y SGBD MySQL, por si puede ser relevante para la respuesta de la pregunta.

Comment: O bien utilizas el `UPPER` donde lo vayas a usar y ya te digo que no es para tanto, yo en el SQL server tengo que usar constantemente `LTRIM(RTRIM(campo)) as campo` porque los devuelve con espacios por configuración del propio ERP o bien hacer un update en todas las tablas con el nombre igual.

Comment: También puedes cambiar la COLLATION de la base de datos para que no distinga entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (accent insensible)

Comment: ¿Estaría bien la segunda consulta que he hecho yo con el UPPER? Porque realmente al probarla en MySQL no da error, pero tampoco me actualiza los campos con diferencias entre mayus/minus.

Comment: Roger, ¿con lo de cambiar la COLLATION te refieres a UTF-8 General CI/UTF-8 Spanish-CI etc.? ¿O a qué exactamente?

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no asignar una COLLATION del tipo `ci`? Las que terminan así son *case insensitive* (de ahí `ci`), Significa que no toma en cuenta si la letra está en mayúscula/minúscula, acento/no acento... Esto te ayuda a controlar duplicados y a hacer comparaciones sin mayor dificultad. Muchas veces tienes problemas a mitad de camino porque no preparaste bien el viaje en el origen, quizá es lo que pasa aqui, no has definido tus datos de la mejor manera en la tabla.

Comment: O sea, que con COLLATION, de lo que hablamos es de poner UTF-8 General CI, por ejemplo, ¿no?

Comment: Sí. Pero lee la documentación antes de decidir la COLLATION que vas a aplicar. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/139752/29967) he tratado de explicar con ejemplos cómo funciona, pero OJO, allí se recomienda usar `utf8_spanish2_ci` porque en aquel contexto se necesita que `ch` sean tratadas como una letra. Para una BD que maneja datos en castellano, la COLLATION que se suele usar es `utf8_spanish_ci`, pero repito, debes decidir según la necesidad que tengas. [En esta página](https://collation-charts.org/mssql/) te explican de forma clara cómo funciona cada COLLATION.

Comment: La consulta con el `UPPER` es errónea, debe ser `UPPER(d.proveedor) = UPPER(a.proveedor)`

Comment: ```UPDATE articulos_nuevos a INNER JOIN diccionario d ON UPPER(d.proveedor) = UPPER(a.proveedor) AND UPPER(d.categoria) = UPPER(a.categoria) SET a.Familia_ERP = d.Familia_ERP, a.Subfamilia_erp = d.Subfamilia_erp``` ¿Está bien esta consulta? No me da error, pero tampoco me actualiza los campos que yo quiero.